# Is it possible to add payment component while still working in Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, payment

I am designing a Mobile App using Expo and React Native for IOS & Android. The users be charged money and it will charge the account/card/PayPal that is on file that they upload into the app. Is it possible to do this while still working out of Expo or will I have to eject before doing anything this complex?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't right now. Expo is creating in App payment abilities and is hoping them to have them ready in the first half of 2021.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall expo support payments but only on bare workflow.
but you can maybe use stripe, but keep in mind that stripe is good only for external usage.

Comment: Can you elaborate with what you mean by "external usage?"

Comment: for example buying a shirt , but not buying an in app product , additional permissions or premium account .

Comment: So if it's an external product like a shirt, stripe supports it, and if it's an in-app service, it does not without a premium account?

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, for in app items like subscriptions or digital usage you need to use app store.